Assessing Efficiency: Custom Claims and Firebase Admin SDK Implementation in Server Development
We have admin pages on our React website using Next.js. Our user types are defined in Cloud Firestore, but checking the user type for admin-only pages incurs a cost for each read operation. To mitigate this, we considered using custom claims. However, we've read that custom claims should be managed in a secure Firebase Admin SDK environment on a server.
We are concerned that this approach might not be the most efficient solution. We aim to maintain continuous communication between our frontend and backend to set a custom claim for each newly created user and to read each user type.
Is there a simpler, less complex method to achieve this?
